# Informatica - How to Pass queries from a table to SQL Transformation and get the results

Tags: sql, teradata, informatica, informatica-powercenter

SO heres what I am trying to do. 
I have a table which has 2 columns - QC_Check and Query. For each QC_Check I have a query. There are several records like this.

Is there a way using SQL transformation that, I can fetch the SQL query stored in the Query column to Informatica, run the queries in Teradata and get the results stored somewhere.

Comment: I don't know how to do this in Informatica, but if it's a TD table, why don't you create a Stored Procedure to run those checks using Dynamic SQL?

Comment: Stored Procedure can be done. However, its not an option right now as per the requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although, I have not tried it myself, this should be possible using SQL transformation in Query mode with Dynamic SQL Queries.
Use the table with Query column as a source. Create a SQL transformation with Query mode. Connect the Query column to the SQL transformation.
[image]

Write ~Query_Port~ in the SQL editor in the SQL transformation:

[image]

If you want to capture the results from your query, you have to configure output ports for columns you retrieve from the database.

Comment: Hi Samik. I tried this, however I am not able to capture my output and the query string is getting saved in the target. Can you elaborate on what you meant by "f you want to capture the results from your query, you have to configure output ports for columns you retrieve from the database."